# A complex data not sure how to explain it

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Hi I have a table called Users and a table called friends, friends table have two data types UserID and FriendID, (foreign key of both data types to primary key of the Users table),

I need to give an ID and find a list of that persons friends'name, I am not sure if I have designed the tables wrongly or I should rewrite the query.

my query is as following, (so far it just shows the details of first matched person)

```
 SELECT Users.Name 
 FROM Users 
 WHERE Users.ID = SELECT Friends.UserID 
                  FROM Friends,Users 
                  WHERE Users.ID = (Select Users.ID  
                                    From Users 
                                    WHERE Users.Username = 'John')
```

Comment: You need to ask something in order for someone to answer

Comment: how about posting some sample data and the table structures, then what you want as the result of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Users.Name FROM Users WHERE Users.ID IN  -- Get names that belongt to ID's
(SELECT FriendID FROM Friends WHERE UserID =    -- All ID's of the Friends of 
(SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE Name = 'John')) -- Johns ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by changing the first = to IN

Answer (score -1):

is this you want to achieve ??
User

1. UserID (PK)
2. Name

Friend

1. FriendID (PK)
2. UserID (FK)

   `select User.Name from User u join Friend f on f.UserID = u.UserID where Name                = 'John'`